# I can't scroll the login page, even when the keyboard appears it still scrolls

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-scrollbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQdEV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60oCz.png)

i am using TextFormField

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

You used `resizetoavoidbottominset` property to `true`. That's why you're not able to scroll. Hide or remove this line and test again.

Comment: I've replaced it and it still doesn't scroll

Comment: You're using customScrollView. Have any problems using SingleChildScrollView? Can you make a test by wrapping with it or replace.

Comment: yes I have used SingleChildScrollView
but this hasn't worked

Comment: Share your code if possible and also an image of what you want to achieve. I can try to figure out a solution

Comment: https://github.com/FARID-NR/api_app

this is my code

Comment: It's scrolling fine. I've tested your login view. But, your SS code and github code are not same.

Comment: sorry this is correct

https://github.com/FARID-NR/api_app/tree/test

Comment: Hey bro, I tested your code again. Just remove or hide this line resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, It's working fine and perfect.
Don't forget to upvote on the answer if it'll work fine

Comment: it's not working on my device, is there a reason ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/mzgqZUWsmmA

this is what happened to my device

Comment: but strangely when i run it again with the keyboard on, this new page can be scrolled, but if the keyboard is not active and i run again then the page can't be scrolled

Comment: If you think it is ok but still not working try flutter clean and flutter pub get. See here how I solve it and how it works for me.  https://fastupload.io/hipJoL6lG87Rmif/file

Comment: I've done a cache clean and removed resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false but that hasn't worked either

Comment: I also tried running it on emulator and it still doesn't work

Comment: Come here, let's have a try
https://meet.google.com/ogi-taum-xem